# The difference between using useState with [] and without it, and also with {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Hey guys I have two questions about the react.js hook. Please help. Get confused a few days :(
1.What is the difference between **using [] and without []** in the useState()
I noticed that when using **useState([])** the console.log(array) will be like

```
(100) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

However when I use **useState()** in my code it will look like the following, and I couldn't use **array.length** there will be an error saying **"cannot read property length of undefined"**

```
Array(100)
0: {id: "181913649", name: "Drake Hotline Bling", url: "https://i.imgflip.com/30b1gx.jpg", width: 1200, height: 1200, …}
1: {id: "112126428", name: "Distracted Boyfriend", url: "https://i.imgflip.com/1ur9b0.jpg", width: 1200, height: 800, …}
2: {id: "87743020", name: "Two Buttons", url: "https://i.imgflip.com/1...
.
.
```

2.Also, when do we use {} in useState({}) ? I do know that {} is for object.Please give some examples :(

Following is the main code App.js:

```
function App() {
  const [array,setarray]=useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
          const {memes} = response.data
          console.log(memes[0].url)

          setarray(memes)
          
      })
  },[])
  console.log(array)
  console.log(array[0])
  console.log(array.length)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Control data={array}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The `useState` function is a React hook, whose argument sets the initial value of the state created. If you pass an array, it will be an array, if you pass an object, it'll be an object, etc. If you don't pass anything, then `undefined` will be used.

Comment: The output of `console.log` is pretty much irrelevant. The argument you pass to `useState` is the **initial value**. Which value to use depends on which value you want the state to have, and what other code expects the value to be. I assume `memes` is an array, so initializing  it to an empty array seems to be the right thing. Also look at what value `Control` expects to get for `data`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `useState()` without passing an argument, the initial value of the state variable (`array`) will be `undefined`. Trying to read the property `length` of `array` (i.e. `array.length`) will then give an error:

```js
const [array, setArray] = useState()

console.log(array) //=> undefined
console.log(array.length) //=> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

If you call `useState([])`, i.e. you pass an empty array as the argument, the initial value of the state variable (`array`) will be an empty array (`[]`). Trying to read the property `length` of `array` (i.e. `array.length`) will then work fine:

```js
const [array, setArray] = useState([])

console.log(array) //=> []
console.log(array.length) //=> 0
```

If you are going to set `array` to an array later – and you are, in the `useEffect()` – it's a good practice to set the initial value to an empty array. Then you can safely treat `array` like it's an array, i.e. you don't have to check if it's `undefined` or an array.

Similarly, you might want to use `{}` as the initial value if your state is later going to be an object. This can be useful to prevent errors. For example:

```js
const [obj, setObj] = useState()

console.log(obj) //=> undefined
console.log(obj.length) //=> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
console.log(Object.entries(obj)) //=> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

// versus

const [obj, setObj] = useState({})

console.log(obj) //=> {}
console.log(obj.length) //=> undefined
console.log(Object.entries(obj)) //=> []
```

(`obj.length` probably doesn't make much sense, but it's just an example.)

Comment: Thank you so much ! It much clearer for me! One more question, when is it better to use useState({}) with curly braces? I mean because when we use useState([]) we can store objects in an array too right? So it seems not necessary to use useState({})?

Comment: `useState([])` sets the initial state value to an empty array. `useState({})` sets the initial state value to an empty object. Which one is more suitable depends on the situation – do you want the state value to be an array or an object? You might also want a boolean (`useState(true)` / `useState(false)`), a string (`useState('some text')`) or something else entirely. Depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets `[]` will create an **Array object** and while using curly brackets `{}` creates a **plain object**.
it's really a matter of how you would like to be able to access the data. you can even set argument to `useState('')`. Without using initial value `useState()` it will be **`undefined`**

Arrays only hold values:

```
const numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5, 35]
const myNumbers = numbers .map(item=> {
    return item* 2
})

Output
[ 4, 6, 8, 10, 70 ]
```

array Objects have key-value pairs. Mostly we use whenever we want to create and store a list of multiple items in a single variable

```
const products = [
    { id: '1', name: 'Foo' },
    { id: '2', name: 'bar' }
];
const myProducts = products.map((item, key) => {
    return (
        <tr key={key}>
            <td>{item.id}</td>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
        </tr>
    );
});
```

furthermore, if you **iterate** data using **map()** `{}` this give you **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): products.map is not a function** as it is plain object.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState({});

products.map((item) => {
    return item; })
```

by using `const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);` you will get `products.length` = **0** without error.